# Creating a foreign key column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add a column to the table in MSSQL which mimics one of the existing column. However, since I am fairly new I am not sure how to go about this. I am trying to create another column called ProbPost which mimics the ProbLG. I have a query that helped me find the relationship for the current column ProbLG DO I have to create the column and then create the foreign key for this. Can anyone please provide me with an example. 
Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Foreign Column Key example]

[image]

Comment: you need to add the column, then add the constraint as [alter table x add column probpost int null; alter table x add constraint fk2 foreign key probpost references probablities(id)]

Comment: Make sure to do some more research next time. There are tons of examples about how to create a FK. Note Google keyword:
'SQL Creating a foreign key column' => Top Entry. Exactly what you were looking after.

Comment: @FabianBigler I see, and agree, but he was wondering about a simple command column duplication, it's okay, We roll

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE Productions ADD ProbPost int NULL ;

ALTER TABLE Productions
Add Constraint Productions_ProbPost_FK FOREIGN KEY ( ProbPost ) references Pobabilities(ID)
```